# Can I cancel a G26 that’s already underway?

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, troubleshooting, bed-leveling, g-code

I’m spending hours trying to get a bed mesh that gives me a reliable first layer.  I’ve got CHEP’s concentric square pattern printing reliably, but real objects still fail, and the G26 test pattern in Marlin FW is failing immediately.

Can I kill a G26 R999 that’s already begun, once I get filament balling up on my nozzle?

Comment: You can pull the power cord from the socket, or reset the board.

Answer (score 1):

## Not with a command

You can not cancel **any** commands once they have started to execute unless you abort the print or powercycle: any normal interrupt command you send (like "pause") is queued after the current command is executed in the line.

## Aborting is losing your print

So you need to trigger a function without a G or M code. The most common solution is Powercycling - which forces the board to *hard* re-boot.

Another way to force a reboot is to connect the "reset" pin with 5V.

Or you connect the printer to a machine via a USB connection, which, to initialize that connection forces a reboot.

Another solution is using the machine's "Abort print" function. This bypasses the command queue and triggers pretty much a *soft reboot*.

**In all cases, the print is lost.**